# How to set a variable as query result in a MySQL stored procudure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, percona

A rather simple question, but I can only find answers to more complex questions.

I'm working on a stored procudure and am currently inside a REPEAT loop. I need to run the following query in the loop to get the 1 column value that is returned (only 1 record will be returned). This will need to be stored as a var to be used later in the loop.

> SELECT photo_id FROM photos ORDER BY photo_id DESC LIMIT 1;

How do I set that to 'last_photo_id' to be used later in the stored procdure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DECLARE total_products INT DEFAULT 0
 SELECT COUNT  INTO total_products
 FROM products
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do something like this:

```
SELECT @varname := photo_id
FROM photos
ORDER BY photo_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

That is, if you are sure there's no other way to do what you want to do than in a loop. For SQL works best when you use it for set-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function
So for example

```
  SET i_camera_count = get_camera_count(i_photo_camera_data_id);
```

and then make a function like this.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_camera_count` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_camera_count`(camera_id_2 INT(10)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_return_val INT;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_return_val = -1;


 SELECT x FROM y WHERE camera_id = camera_id_2

  RETURN v_return_val;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```